# python docstring style leaving blank spaces

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, read-the-docs

I'm using docstrings with `sphinx` for documenting a project. It's working generally fine but as you see in the below image, I'm losing a lot of space in the "parameters" section.

Is there a way to remove that "parameters" while keeping it in the class docstring? Or leaving a blank line and indenting each parameter to the left? I've tried several options but they don't seem to have effect on this style

[image: GASearchCV]

EDIT:
This is what the docstring looks like:

```py
class GASearchCV(ClassifierMixin, RegressorMixin):
    """
    Evolutionary optimization over hyperparameters.

    Long description..
    """

    def __init__(self,
                 estimator):
        """
        Parameters
        ----------
        estimator : estimator object, default=None
        estimator object implementing 'fit'
        The object to use to fit the data.
        """
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does your current docstring look like?

Comment: Hi, I added a sample in the original question. Thanks

Comment: The code for the class is not syntactically correct. The docstring is not indented. Please provide the exact code used to create the output shown in the image.

Comment: You are right, thanks, just pasted the exact code, just left 1 parameter because there are more than 10

Comment: I cannot replicate the exact output shown in the question. I also don't understand what you mean by "losing a lot of space". You are not following the NumPy style conventions. The first line of a parameter description should be just `paramname : type`. See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html#google-vs-numpy